# Laravel 5 Angular 5 - row delete operation

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, angular5

I have a Laravel5.5 and Angular5 project where Angular consumes the API from Laravel. The codes under product.component.html is:

```
<button (click)="deleteProduct(product.id)">Delete This</button>
```

The code under product.component.ts is below:

```
deleteProduct(id){
      console.log('product ID= '+id);
      this.productService.getdeleteProduct(id);

}
```

In the product.service.ts, I have called the API

```
getdeleteProduct(id): Observable<any>{
  console.log("get p id ="+ id);
  const url = `${this.url}/api/product/`+id;
  console.log(url); // http://localhost:8000/api/product/8
  return this.http.delete(url,{headers: new HttpHeaders({Authorization:'Bearer '+ this.token})});
}
```

And below is my Laravel delete record code:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product->delete();

    return response()->json($product);
}
```

The values of the product id are returns well in the console however, from phpMyAdmin, I see the record corresponds to the 'id' is not getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that I forgot to write the code in product.component.ts. It should be as like:

```
deleteProduct(id){
      console.log('product ID= '+id);
      this.productService.getdeleteProduct(id).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.states = data.states;

      }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

          this.dataInvalid = true;
          this.formSubmitting = false;
          if(err.error instanceof Error){
            console.log("haseoor");
            this.formErrors.push(err.error.message);
          } else {
              const errors = err.error;
              const items = [];
              for (const key in errors) {
                if (errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  items.push(errors[key]);
                }
              }
              for (const k in items[1]) {
                if (items[1].hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                  this.formErrors.push(items[1][k][0]);
                }
              }
            }
        }
      )

  }
```